# Struck vs Stricken

Tags: meaning, word-choice, past-participles, variants, strong-verbs

Is *struck* or *stricken* correct in these sentences?

1. The house *was* **stricken / struck** by lightning.
2. The house *had* been **stricken / struck** by lightning.
3. He *was* **stricken / struck** by grief, cancer, etc.

**Can *by* be replaced with *with* in the sentence above (Sentence No. 3)?**

4. The judge *had* **struck / stricken** it from the record.
5. It *was* **struck / stricken** from the record.

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain your prior research results so we can understand why you are confused. Otherwise this is likely be closed either as General Reference or as Proofreading.

Comment: Well, that source is certainly wrong then. The answer to both your questions is *yes*.

Comment: To both my questions? Don't understand your response. Which are the correct choices above? I say (1) struck (2) struck (3) stricken - both 'by' and 'with' are correct (4) stricken (5) stricken

Comment: The main problem with your question is that you assume there is a right answer and a wrong answer. Why do you think that any of those are wrong?  The reason the answer is *yes* to all your questions is that you can use either, at least and especially when it comes to striking things from the record or being stricken with some illness.

Comment: [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stricken?searchDictCode=all) claims that as a verb, *stricken* is a 
"North American or archaic past participle of strike". But as an adjective, *stricken with grief/cancer* is still in use. So for the U.K., you should only use *stricken* in (3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TMTOWTDI

You assume that there’s exactly one “right” answer and exactly one “wrong” answer, and that just isn’t the way things work in language.  Different speakers will use different variants at different times (so will the same speaker), whether this is the participle or the preposition that goes with it.

That does not mean one is wrong and the other right. If you play around with Google Books, you find plenty of variation even in recent years, particularly in North America.  Don’t speak of **correctness**; look instead at **usage**.

That said, under **most** circumstances the past participle of *strike* is now simply *struck*, although *stricken* is still sometimes used in North America even apart from the two principal exceptions I list below. Despite *struck* being the more common variant for the past participle in today’s English, two main areas are still dominated by the *stricken* variant:

1. When it concerns some malady, trouble, or affliction: *stricken with/by grief, fever, remorse, refugees*.

   [image: Ngram: stricken by grief]

   [image: Ngram: Stricken with paralysis]

   OED citations for this sense include the following:

   > - 1837 Carlyle Fr. Rev. I. v. v, ― Hot old Marquis Mirabeau lies stricken down, at Argenteuil.
   > - 1891 E. Peacock N. Brendon II. 199 ― The Duke had been stricken by paralysis.
   > - 1891 Speaker 11 July 36/2 ― The fear is··that public life may be stricken with sterility in consequence of this veto.

   As you see by those citations, both [*stricken by*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stricken%20by%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) and [*stricken with*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stricken%20with%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) wind up getting used:

   [image: Ngram: stricken by/with]
2. When it is means to remove something, especially in legal language such as striking things from the record or striking jurors from the case: *the next three words shall be stricken out; the next juror stricken by the state; the judge ordered it stricken from the record*.

   [image: Ngram: stricken from the record]

   OED citations for this sense include:

   > - 1829 Rep. Supreme Court Tennessee (1832) IX. 229 ― That an attorney may be stricken from the roll for good cause, none can doubt.
   > - 1861 Congr. Globe 18 Feb. 947/2, ― I will read the words to be stricken out.
   > - 1906 Federal Reporter (1907) CXLVII. 451 ― All of the testimony given by the witness··is withdrawn and stricken out of this case.
   > - 1915 Southwestern Reporter CLXXV. 661/1 ― No further steps··were taken in the case until the February term, 1904, of the Magoffin circuit court, when it was stricken from the docket.
   > - 1938 Congress Rec. 24 May 7405/2 ― That the Committee do··report the bill back to the House with the recommendation that the enacting clause be stricken out.
   > - 1957 Reports Supreme Court Kansas (1958) CLXXXI. 623 ― In our opinion the reply was erroneously stricken.
   > - 1965 Pacific Reporter CCCCIV. 230/2 ― Where··a second clause appears which expresses a different intent and declares a life estate plus a remainder which is void under the rule, the qualifying clause will be stricken.
   > - 1978 N.Y. Times 29 Mar. b3/4 ― Over strong objections from the prosecutor, Sybil R. Moses, Judge William J. Arnold ordered the question stricken.

Although those are the two main hold-outs where *stricken* still prevails as the past participle, you can still sometimes find it used from time to time in North America for situations where *struck* is now more common, such as this recent example:

> - 1976 National Observer (U.S.) 9 Oct. 7/4 ― A new trend in comics has stricken down many of the old taboos.

Normally things like old trends or old court decisions are *struck down* by newer ones.  But this is not guaranteed, as the previous citation shows. Just because some people say things differently doesn’t mean they’re wrong; they’re just different.

English has many, many past-tense forms and past participles where multiple possibilities are commonly used.  Don’t think there can be only one way to do it.  Language is not arithmetic. There’s more than one way to do it.

Regarding which preposition — if any — gets  used with *strike*, it just depends since there are so many possibilities, especially in the historical record. Here as before, several possible choices exist, all equally viable.

What would I myself personally say?  I would probably say:

> People who survive being ***struck*** by lightning are often ***stricken*** with debilitating after-effects for the rest of their lives.

As you see, both forms can certainly be used, particularly when a shaded nuance is desired as in my example sentence: the first is a blow, the second a trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Struck is used for any physical contact where stricken is used as more of an abstraction, meaning to be afflicted by or removed from depending on the context.

1) The house was struck by lightning

2) The boy was stricken with pox

3) He has been stricken from home

Comment: Hi & welcome to EL&U. Although this does provide some explanation in answer to the question, please note that answers on EL&U are expected to be authoritative, detailed, and **explain why it is correct**. You could edit your answer to provide more information & explanation. Where appropriate, answers are also expected to include links to definitive sources that substantiate your answer. For further guidance, see [How to Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and take the [EL&U Site Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Incidentally, did you realise that you were answer a Q. that was asked over 4 years ago (Jan 2015)?