# "I have strived" vs "I have striven"

Tags: word-choice, formality, writing, past-participles, variants

In a college application essay, I am trying to write the sentence along the lines of:

> I have always **strived** to achieve my goals.

Should I say *strived* or *striven*?

According to [this article at grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/usage/strove-strived-striven/), *striven* is correct but *strived* is gaining popularity. Which is better in a formal essay?

Comment: No one can decide this for you. It is a matter of opinion only, and what image you are trying to present of yourself.

Comment: @tchrist What are the two images given off by the two words, or is it purely a matter of personal preference?

Comment: You can get some idea from this [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223539/struck-vs-stricken?s=1|3.6421).

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+always+strived+to%2Chave+always+striven+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20always%20strived%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20always%20striven%20to%3B%2Cc0) support my perceptions.

Comment: 'I have strived' sounds right to me. It's what I would write or speak. 'have striven' has the stilted fell of middle English,

Comment: "I have always fought to achieve my goals."  Or look [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/strive).

Comment: Whichever you use, 50% of the readers think you are wrong. 50% of readers are not sure. Of the 50% who are sure, half are wrong themselves. "I have always worked hard to achieve my goals".

Comment: I think it depends where you live. In England and Canada we use the old past tense forms like "striven" and "lit" and so forth while in the US people use "strived" and "lighted".

Comment: As a native English speaker from southern Appalachia, "have striven" is what sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 5):

'I have always striven to reach my goals', is correct in my opinion. I have heard 'strived' used and think that is part of the trend to regularize all the verb endings in English, forgetting the origins of the language. That would make it much easier for non-English speakers to learn. 'have striven' is pluperfect tense, whereas 'strove' is past tense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 60 years old, read a lot and am well-educated. Until today, 1/21/16, I had never heard the usage 'I have striven.' I always said, read and heard 'I have strived, OR I strove.' I heard it in a radio ad today.  I'm amazed to learn striven has primary usage, and for a much longer period of time 
(see chart on These Google Ngrams).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+strived%2CI+have+striven&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20strived%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20striven%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

The actual forms are `to strive`, `strive(s)`, `striving`, `strove`, & `striven`.
When `strived` is used instead of an authentic form of the word, it sometimes replaces the simple past `strove` and other times it replaces the past participle `striven`.
If you are going to do this to irregular verbs like strive, then you will be saying "*I have been bited by the dog*", "*The writed warning was issued*", and "*I knowed it all*".